# How to resolve an error: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been checking several posts on stack overflow for this error which I also got while I was trying to add a SQL query for retrieving a column `tblAR.ARID` as following:

```
SELECT tblAR.ARID,
@GP = (Sum(ard.Amount))
-(Sum((CASE WHEN MaterialNumber='REBATE' THEN [qty] 
            WHEN ard.Amount<0 THEN -1*ABS([qty]) 
            ELSE ABS([qty]) 
        END)))
FROM 
tblMMMaterials mm 
INNER JOIN tblARDetail ard ON mm.MatID = ard.MatID 
INNER JOIN tblAR arh ON ard.ARID = arh.ARID
WHERE arh.Date=@RunDate
```

I came to know I can't do both in single query. So, I divided the query into two as following:

```
SELECT 
@GP = (Sum(ard.Amount))
-(Sum((CASE WHEN MaterialNumber='REBATE' THEN [qty] 
            WHEN ard.Amount<0 THEN -1*ABS([qty]) 
            ELSE ABS([qty]) 
        END)))
FROM 
tblMMMaterials mm 
INNER JOIN tblARDetail ard ON mm.MatID = ard.MatID 
INNER JOIN tblAR arh ON ard.ARID = arh.ARID
WHERE arh.Date=@RunDate 

select tblAR.ARID from tblAR
WHERE tblAR.Date=@RunDate
```

Although it doesn't give me any error, I am not confident if this later sql code is 100% ideal. In other words, I want to know if it is enough to include 'WHERE' condition in the second query i.e. `WHERE tblAR.Date=@RunDate`. Please help

Comment: It's not necessarily the same, since the `INNER JOIN`s could be filtering or  multiplying some rows depending on the data on those tables. It would be better if you explain what it is that you actually want to do

Comment: @Lamak: thanks lot for responding. Actually, I need the ARIDs which fall under the `rundate` and satisfy everything that it is doing for `GP`. I am not sure if I also need to include those inner joins for it. So, I ended up including only where condition. This gave me bunch of ARIDs

Answer (score 0):

No they are no same since you have `JOIN` involved in the query. You can repeat the query though like

```
SELECT 
@GP = (Sum(ard.Amount))
-(Sum((CASE WHEN MaterialNumber='REBATE' THEN [qty] 
            WHEN ard.Amount<0 THEN -1*ABS([qty]) 
            ELSE ABS([qty]) 
        END)))
FROM 
tblMMMaterials mm 
INNER JOIN tblARDetail ard ON mm.MatID = ard.MatID 
INNER JOIN tblAR arh ON ard.ARID = arh.ARID
WHERE arh.Date=@RunDate;

SELECT tblAR.ARID
FROM 
tblMMMaterials mm 
INNER JOIN tblARDetail ard ON mm.MatID = ard.MatID 
INNER JOIN tblAR arh ON ard.ARID = arh.ARID
WHERE arh.Date=@RunDate
```